# How to connect Wiremock server with Aerospike (i.e., as Cache DB) with GraphQL using Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, caching, graphql, wiremock, aerospike

I'm planning/trying to implement a sandbox functionality for the **GraphQL** schema's using **Wiremock Server** and **Aerospike** (i.e., Should work **as Cache DB**) using **Spring Boot 3.x**.

I've done some samples with, **Spring Boot & GraphQL** and **Spring Boot & Aerospike**, combinations.

Can someone suggest the design or repository or other info/docs to integrate all the components (i.e., Spring Boot, GraphQL, Wiremock & Aerospike)?

- Spring Boot & GraphQL - Done sample project. Able to perform Query/Mutations
- Spring Boot & Aerospike - Done sample project. Able to see the records inserted using **AQL** (**Aerospike Query Language**).
- Integrating all these components (i.e., Spring Boot, GraphQL, Wiremock & Aerospike) is kind of tricky. Not able to integrate.